# QGIS python functions in relative path?

Tags: qgis, python, file-path

I am using QGIS 2.18.3 to create an atlas. This works well and I now want to call some functions to create richer content in a text box. To do this I am calling a python function from an expression. Works fine.

Since I am working on several computers I would like to keep track of my python code. I am using GitHub for this. However - QGIS takes a global approach and by default places my code in this folder (yes using Windows):

```
C:\Users\raglar\.qgis2\python\expressions
```

I would like to keep the python code related to this project relative to this particular QGIS project file. This way I will be able to keep track of the functions relevant to this particular project. Is this possible?

Comment: I think this post might be related: [Is it possible to distribute custom python expressions along with .qgs file?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209517/is-it-possible-to-distribute-custom-python-expressions-along-with-qgs-file)

Comment: Agree the posting is related. What I am hoping is that this path can somehow be set (or reset) in some way. A script that does this when the project opens would be elegant.

Comment: The variable/path is set somewhere. It is however not available/stated under the variables overview in the expression editor. Being able to append a path would be of great help.